# Gazebo and Ogre meshes

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Why Gazebo lost support of opening ogre meshes directly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/861/gazebo-and-ogre-meshes/) by [rlklaser](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/151/rlklaser/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ogre meshes are not very common, and are not supported by most other applications. Rather than try to support a large range of formats, we have decided to limit ourselves to the most common and/or most universally accepted (collada and stl).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0